# Any working around with Mongodb key can't contain "." or "$"?

Tags: mongodb

This kind of document are not accepted by Mongodb:

```
{'.':1}
```

if encode and decode by hand that's a pain. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Naming Restrictions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#naming-restrictions) on database, collection, and field names have practical purposes.  They try to ensure queries are unambiguous and that valid filenames can be created.

For example:

- MongoDB uses [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to access elements of an array or subdocument.
- MongoDB uses the dollar sign ($) to represent [operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/) (eg. `$inc`).
- [Database names](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#naming-restrictions) correspond to files created in the operating system, and there are reserved characters for path separators and wildcards.

The obvious workaround (which is also [suggested in the MongoDB manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#faq-dollar-sign-escaping)) is to use a different character.  For example, the Unicode full width equivalents of `$` and `.` will display similarly but are not reserved:

- U+FF04 (i.e. “＄”)
- U+FF0E (i.e. “．”)